# How to Capture changing value of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage with a small survey. I want to pre populate some of the answers based on user inputs to previous question.

In the below code, if value of id QR~QID3 depends upon value of QID1_Total. However after the page loaded  and even if the condition is met the textbox is not populated with correct value.

```
.addOnload(function()
{
    if(document.getElementById("QID1_Total").value>15) {
        document.getElementById("QR~QID3").value = "Good";
        }

    else{
        document.getElementById("QR~QID3").value = "Average";
    }

});
```

Comment: You need some listeners on your `QID1_Total` element that triggers this function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#QID1_Total").on("input", function() {
   //statements goes here
});
```

use of `on("input"` will track every inputting event, include drop and paste.

know more about onInput : https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/oninput

> **Here is an Fiddle Example to know how trigger works :**
>   https://jsfiddle.net/5sotpa63/

**An Assumption**

Let Us Say you are using a function, which holds this statement show Good and Average according to users Input.

```
var targetElem  = document.getElementById("QID1_Total");
var showComment = (targetElem,value>15) ? "Good" : "Average";
document.getElementById("QR~QID3").value = showComment;
```

Above code is the shorter method of your own statement mentioned in your question.

Now on Change of the target `QR~QID3` you need to load some content. you utilize the below code as follows.

```
$("#QR~QID3").on("input", function() {
  //your next question loading statements goes here,
  //statements to proceed when you show some comment Good or Average
}).trigger("input");
```

Hope! this could be helpful.

Comment: Actually user cannot enter value in QID1_Total. It shows the sum of other textboxes.

Comment: May be `$("#QID1_Total").on("input", function() {}).trigger('input');`

Comment: If this is the case,  you could use, $("#QID1_Total”).trigger("input") or change

Comment: @RayonDabre - where do i place my if statement in your code?

Comment: Inside function handler... `function(){ /*HERE*/ }`

Comment: would you please add some HTML, so that i can implement it using your HTML? @Glenn

Comment: @Glenn, check my edited answer, this could be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$('#QID1_Total').keydown(function () {

//ur code

});

as the mouse key is pressed in the input field the function is called

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event listener to the "QID1_Total" element.
If you want to run the check while the user changes the input, i.e. after each keypress use the *oninput* event.
If you want to run the check after the user has completed the input, use the *onchange* event. The *onchange* event will only fire after the input loses focus.

You can bind the event listeners by using the addEventListener() function like this:

`document.getElementById("QID1_Total").addEventListener("input", function(){
  //Code goes here
});`

[Here is a JSFiddle showing both methods.](https://jsfiddle.net/martiensk/7zau9L30/)

You also have to use the parseInt() function on the textbox values before you can perform mathematical functions with them.